# in AWS Athena, how to left join that matches only 1 row on the right with high performance?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have 2 tables:

regex_table: contains the regex patterns

| id | regex_pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'hel.*' |
| 2 | '1.*' |

string_table: contains strings

| id | string |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | hell |

The expected result should contain 1 matched string for each regex pattern, like

| regex_pattern | string |
| --- | --- |
| 'hel.*' | hello |
| '1.*' |  |

each regex_pattern only needs one string, so in this example, both `hell` and `hello` can be a match for `'hel.*'`

I need to do this on AWS Athena (presto under the hood) for a giant data set

I've tried:

1. use row_number()

```
select * 
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (
      partition by regex_pattern
      order by string
    ) as rn
  from regex_table
    left join string_table on regexp_like(string, regex_pattern)
)
where rn = 1
```

this works, but too slow because the join has to check all the strings of string table while only one matched string is needed, the rest can be skipped, just like a `break` loop in ruby or python

2. Use Correlated subquery

```
select regex_pattern, 
  (
    select string 
    from string_table 
    where regexp_like(string, regex_pattern) 
    limit 1
  )
from regex_table
```

but received error `Correlated subquery in given context is not supported`

Is there a better way than `left join` to solve this problem in athena?

Currently I have to do this matching in python to take advantage of the `break` loop to break out of looping string_table when a matched string is found. Is it possible to do the same in sql?

Comment: tat doesn't sound very efficient on big tables even in python, you would use a dofferent technique to search in millions of datarows.

Comment: `regexp_like(regex_pattern, string)` should be `regexp_like(string, regex_pattern)` see [the docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_like)